# How to add multiple list views in to sliver list like this in this picture- flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I was trying to make a app like this. how to add that two lists namely today and tomorrow in a Sliver?

[image: this model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st use `CustomScrollView`, then use `MultiSliver` from [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools)

it will be like

```
 - CustomScrollView 
   - SliverAppBar 
   - MultiSliver
      - PinnedHeader(i prefer)
      - Column of Today
   - MultiSliver
      - PinnedHeader(i prefer)
      - Column of next ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. Just make the 'Today' and 'Tomorrow' labels a ListView item which just looks differently. Not every Item in a list has to look identical.

If you internally have two separate data lists, it should be easy to write a wrapper on your data classes.

Comment: could you please provide an example

Comment: @Bazi Where is the problem? in your builder you simply return a list item for today if index < today.length ... if index == today.length you return the label for "tomorrow" and otherwise you return a list item for `tomorrow[index-today.length-1]`?